# install phpMyAdmin with Laravel 5.1

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I try to install phpMyAdmin to work at same server as my Laravel 5.1 app:

SO I try to access phpmyadmin at this url: domain.com/phpmyadmin but I get:

[image]

Yes thats a route problem, but how I can access phpmyadmin?

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but did you make the route for this? that error message mostly comes when route is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to a `public` directory inside Laravel project root directory and add this line **before all** in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin - [L,NC]
```

This should work for you.

Comment: There's no need to do any of that because of the `!-d` option.

Comment: hm,no I get: Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at netracuni.com Port 80

Comment: Did you install phpmyadmin into `laravel_root/public/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: You pointed your server to a `public` directory of Laravel project, so try to install phpmyadmin there or create symlink.

Comment: So you installed phpmyadmin in a `public` directory,  edited `.htaccess` and you still get NotFound exception? If yes, please update your post with current `.htaccess` file contents

Comment: I unistall and install again also change apache.conf file , now work

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it's routing problem.

The request is being passed to the `index.php` instead of the phpMyAdmin folder.

Try putting this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/` in your `.htaccess` file, to be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: There's no need to do any of that because of the `!-d` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an apache server and ubuntu you can follow the steps below

First you need to create a link

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/
```

Then you need to edit the apache conf file to include phpmyadmin apache.conf

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

add the following line to the apache2.conf file

```
 Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Use the following commands to activate it

```
 sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
 sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
```

and finally reload the server

```
 sudo service apache2 reload
```

now you will be able to access the domain/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

just add
`RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin - [L,NC]` before `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` to .htaccess file in the public folder of your laravel project
then `ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /path_to_laravel_project/public`

Answer (score -1):

Where have you actually installed phpmyadmin?

Assuming you're using apache, your `.htaccess` should have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The `!-d` and `!-f` bits say to only rewrite uris that are not pointing to existing directories or files, so the only reason you'd see the laravel error page would be because phpmyadmin does not exist where you think it exists.